# Concise formula for the 4D volume $x^a \cdot y^a \cdot z^b \cdot w^b \le n, where \, x,y,z,w \ge 1$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I've represented this as the following integral, but I haven't found a way to get it into a form that gives me much insight:

$$\int_1^{n^a} \int_1^{n^a \cdot x^{-1}}\int_1^{(n \cdot x^{-{1 \over a}})^b}\int_1^{(n \cdot x^{-{1 \over a}} \cdot y^{-{b \over a}})^b \cdot z^{-1} }\,dw \, dz \, dy \, dx $$

I can use Mathematica to barf out a formula that works, but it's giant and messy and clearly not getting to the heart of the issue.

**Is there a good, concise closed form representation for this 4D volume?**

As a point of reference, I know that for

$$ x^a \cdot y^b \le n, where \, x,y \ge 1$$

the simpler-but-related

$$\int_1^{n^a} \int_1^{(n \cdot x^{-{1 \over a}})^b}\, dy \, dx = {{b \cdot(n^a-1)} - a(n^b-1)\over{a-b}}$$

As an extra bit of information, the limit, as $a$ and $b$ approach 1, for this second equation is

$$n \log n - n + 1$$

and the limit for the value I'm asking about is

$$ {1 \over 6}n (\log n)^3 - {1 \over 2}n (\log n)^2 + n \log n - n + 1$$

Also, I'm not sure what tags to apply to this question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

more general formula for $4$ different powers $x^a y^b z^c w^d$ is in fact even nicer

$$
\frac{a^3 n^{\frac{1}{a}}}{(a-b) (a-c) (d-a)}+\frac{b^3 n^{\frac{1}{b}}}{(a-b) (b-c)
   (b-d)}+\frac{c^3 n^{\frac{1}{c}}}{(a-c) (c-b) (c-d)}+\frac{d^3
   n^{\frac{1}{d}}}{(a-d) (d-b) (d-c)}+1
$$

The limit when all $a,b,c,d\to 1$ indeed gives

$$
-n+\frac{1}{6} n \log ^3(n)-\frac{1}{2} n \log ^2(n)+n \log (n)+1
$$

Answer (score 1):

Is this concise enough?

$$
-\frac{a^2 (a-3 b) n^{\frac{1}{a}}}{(a-b)^3}+\frac{b^2 (b-3 a)
   n^{\frac{1}{b}}}{(a-b)^3}+\frac{a n^{\frac{1}{a}} \log (n)}{(a-b)^2}+\frac{b
   n^{\frac{1}{b}} \log (n)}{(a-b)^2}+1
$$

Comment: Although this answers my basic question, I think your other answer gets more to the heart of what I was after - the pattern is much more clear and easier to extrapolate from.  Thanks!

Comment: Please [merge your two profiles](http://math.stackexchange.com/contact) into a single one.